# Using the deep:true query option with a dojo ObjectStore adapter

Tags: datagrid, dojo, datastore

I'm new to Dojo, and I'm trying to get my head wrapped around some pretty basic concepts before my partner and I embark on a new project. I've been successful in using the ItemFileWriteStore to get data returned from an ajax request into a DataGrid, but I would like to use the new Memory store instead. I am using the ObjectStore adapter to wrap the Memory store, and data is being populated in the grid.

One thing has me worried. In the example code I'm running, there is some nested nodes in the JSON object I'm using to populate the grid. It's one of the Countries JSON object they use in the dojo documentation. Here's a little snippet of that object:

```
'items': [
{ 'name':'Africa', 'type':'continent', children:[
    { 'name':'Egypt', 'type':'country' },
    { 'name':'Kenya', 'type':'country', children:[
        { 'name':'Nairobi', 'type':'city' },
        { 'name':'Mombasa', 'type':'city' } ]
    },
    { 'name':'Sudan', 'type':'country', 'children':
        { 'name':'Khartoum', 'type':'city' }
    } ]
   },
 ]
```

In the DataGrid instantiation, I send in a query and then I set the qureyOptions to {deep:true} like so:

```
var grid = new DataGrid({
    style: "width: 500px; height: 300px;",
    store: this._geoStore,
    structure: layoutGeo,
    rowSelector: '20px',
    columnReordering: true,
    query: {},
    queryOptions: { deep: true },
    rowsPerPage: 20
}, document.createElement("div"));
```

When I use the old ItemFileWriteStore, this works fine, and ALL the nested data is essentially flattened out and placed in the grid as I would expect. However, when I switch it over to a Memory store wrapped in an ObjectStore adapter, the only data displayed in the grid is the top most parent of the data object. In the case of the sample data, only the data associated with Africa, but none of its children, are displayed. So it seems that the queryOptions {deep:true} statement has no affect when using the Memory store.

Is there some way of getting nested data within the JSON objects into a data grid using a Memory store wrapped in an ObjectStore? I would have thought that the wrapper class would have taken care of this, and it might, but I don't know how to fix it.

For all who help, thank you very much for your time and willingness to share your expertise. I really have studied the dojo docs and web for a long time trying to figure this stuff out. I fear I may have glossed over something obvious and am hoping you all can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blogged about the store changes at http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/03/dojo-implementing-viewmodelstore.html

The code here uses the new store object but brings the reference notation from the data api.  All objects would be considered top level objects and query-able.  I did not implement the logic to pull out nested objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response Craig. I may have to contact you sometime to you some questions about this. I'm thinking right now that I would need to learn how to use the getChildren and getParent methods in relationship to other widgets in the dojo toolkit. I haven't looked into those, but I can see there might be a need for hierarchical data interchanges.